# Calculate limit points of sequence

Tags: limits, analysis

Find the limit points of the sequence $(a_n)$ with

$$a_n=\frac{6n^2}{2n^2+5n+3} \sin{\left( \frac{2 n \pi}{3}\right)}, n \in \mathbb{N}^{\star}$$

Then compute $\lim \inf a_n, \lim \sup a_n$.

That's what I thought:

For $n=3k$, $\sin{\left( \frac{ 2 n \pi}{3}\right)}=\frac{1}{2} i e^{-2 i \pi k}-\frac{1}{2} i e^{2 i \pi k}$.

For $n=3k+1$, $\sin{\left( \frac{2 n \pi}{3}\right)}=\frac{1}{2} e^{-2 i \pi k-\frac{i \pi}{6}}+\frac{1}{2} e^{2 i \pi k+\frac{ i \pi}{6}}$.

For $n=3k+2$, $\sin{\left( \frac{2 n \pi }{3}\right)}=-\frac{1}{2} e^{\frac{i \pi}{6}-2 i \pi k}-\frac{1}{2} e^{2 i \pi k-\frac{i \pi}{6}}$.

Do we take now the limit $k \to \infty$ to find the limit point?

In the affirmative, all the limits tend to infinity so the limit point is $\infty$.

Does this make sense? Then $\lim \sup a_n$ is $+\infty$ and so is also $\lim \inf a_n$.

Comment: Why do you say everything tends to $\infty$?  The rational fraction goes to $3$ and the sine is bounded between $-1$ and $+1$.

Comment: Yes, I see. @saulspatz And how does this help?

Comment: Can you guess what the lim sup and lim inf are?  What's the biggest value you can imagine that a subsequence  could approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have, for each $n\in\Bbb N$,$$\sin\left(\frac{2n\pi}3\right)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }3\mid n\\-\frac{\sqrt3}2&\text{ if }3\mid(n-1)\\\frac{\sqrt3}2&\text{ if }3\mid(n-2).\end{cases}$$On the other hand,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{6n^2}{2n^2+5n+3}=3.$$So,$$\limsup a_n=\frac{3\sqrt3}2\quad\text{and}\quad\liminf a_n=-\frac{-3\sqrt3}2.$$This follows from the fact that the superior limit of a bounded sequence is the largest limit of its convergent subsequences and that the inferior limit is the smallest limit of its convergent subsequences.

Comment: I think I understand. So the limit points are $0, -\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{2}$, yes??? @JoseCarlosSantos

Comment: Yes. Those three numbers are the only numbers which are limits of subsequences of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$.

Comment: Thank you @JoseCarlosSantos